# Why OptaPlanner gives "Bailing out of neverEnding selector to avoid infinite loop." error when I used @PlanningPin?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I've red the optaplanner documentation and @PlanningPin usage is very simple.
My PlanningEntity is:

```
@PlanningEntity()
public class CrewGroupAssignment extends AbstractPersistable {
```

I've used PlanningPin inside PlanningEntity like this:

```
@PlanningPin
private Boolean pinned = true;
   public Boolean getPinned() {
      return pinned;
   }

   public void setPinned(Boolean pinned) {
      this.pinned = pinned;
   }
```

If this.pinned is false there is no problem, algorithm works perfectly, however, when it is true (PlanningVariable inside this class set with a value, it is not empty) it gives error:

> [FilteringEntitySelector] WARN  - Bailing out of neverEnding selector
>   (Filtering(FromSolutionEntitySelector(CrewGroupAssignment))) to avoid
>   infinite loop.

If PlanningVariable inside this class not set with a value, then it doesn't work also. Why it gives this error for this reason?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've seen this before. It's because all your entities are pinned. There's a jira to improve OptaPlanner's behavior: it should simply end solving immediatly when starting from a dataset with no movable entities (either they are are none or the are all immovable (for example because they are pinned)).

Comment: Could you share issue solved optaplanner version about this problem. I've upgraded optaplanner version to the 7.32.0.Final and issue still continue.

Comment: Then it's not because of there not being any movable entities (= all entities are pinned). Would be interesting to know why there are no selectable moves.